# use linq to group by and then run select query with where condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class, OrderInfo shown below,

```
 class OrderInfo
 {
    string Product
    boolean NoIssues
 }
```

I have a list of OrderInfo. What I would like to do is to know for each product if there is an issue or not. So below is an example of my list.

```
 ProductList

 Product      NoIssues
 ABC          true
 ABC          true
 ABC          false
 ABC          true
 EFG          true
 EFG          true
 EFG          true
 EFG          true
 EFG          true
```

Below is the result I would like.

```
Result      
ABC       false
EFG       true
```

So I was going to use LINQ to group by product to get a unique list of products and then loop through this list to run a select query where I filter on NoIssues = false. However not sure how to do this or if this is the best way

```
 var res = (from ord in ProductList
            group ord by ord.Product).ToList()
```

So I believe the code above will give me a unique list of products that I can loop through. But not sure whats happens if I use a select statement with a where condition where nothing is returned?

Comment: Why don't you just add the `where` clause to the main query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**All**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541(v=vs.100).aspx) :-

```
List<OrderInfo> result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Product)
                             .Select(x => new OrderInfo
                                       {
                                           Product = x.Key,
                                           NoIssues = x.All(z => z.NoIssues)
                                       }).ToList();
```

Or if you prefer query syntax:-

```
List<OrderInfo> result = (from ord in ProductList
                         group ord by ord.Product into g
                         select new OrderInfo
                               {
                                    Product = g.Key,
                                    NoIssues = g.All(x => x.NoIssues)
                               }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create new Product objects for this, I would go with:

```
var result = from product in ProductList
             group product by product.Product into productGroup
             select productGroup.Where(p => !p.NoIssues)
                                .DefaultIfEmpty(productGroup.First())
                                .First();
```

Otherwise, @Rahul Singh's answer is more intuitive.